# How can I access data from code behind to MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, code-behind

I have this data in code behind

```
public partial class PruebaPage : ContentPage
{
    public string Datas { get; set; } // data that I want to access
```

and this is my View Model

```
namespace PuebasTemplate.ViewModels
{
    public class PruebaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Is there some way to access  public string `Datas` from my MVVM `PruebaViewModel`?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way? Sure. The page could pass itself into the VM via some method or property for one.

### But you **shouldn't** do that

View models are not supposed to know *anything* about their view, certainly not the tight coupling of having an actual reference to it. Sounds like you have an XY problem; and that data should live in the view model to start with.

Comment: thanks for your reply! the problem I have is the following: there is an event of a Syncfusion (a masked entry) control that I could not bind to my viewModel I could only capture the events on the code behind, the only solution I could think of is to access the data that are in code behind from my viewModel

Comment: @ArmandoAlvarez In that case I would react to the events in the view and set the appropriate VM property there; still just view knowing about the view model and not the other way around.